# Is it right to deduce intention/action from circumstantial evidence from position of a skeptic?

Tags: skepticism

In many cases it might not be possible to have [direct evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_evidence) to conclude intention/action of a person. Only [circumstantial evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstantial_evidence) may be available.
From position of a skeptic, is it right to deduce the intention of a person or actual action of a person from strong circumstantial evidence? Is there anything written about it or said about it? Or is it a matter of subjective opinion?

Comment: Depending upon the version of skepticism this has a wide range of answers.  The simplest is Sextus Empiricus's: Since intention is always something that one can never clearly ascertain -- even when it is stated it is often misleading -- the only just approach is to leave decisions about it unresolved, and find other ways to decide one's path.  But I am not sure he is the kind of skeptic you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for directing me. I was sure that this would be the case in the hard and pure skepticism like that of Empiricus but mainly I want to know whether it is right to do this on the pragmatic or practical skepticism that many people choose to follow now to decide their beliefs (skepticism as a tool rather than philosophy). I know I am sounding vague. Anyways, thanks!